# how to create a unique routing pattern in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have an application that  only users can access /user and /user/* parts but some URLs like /userABC (/user...) should be accessible for all visitors.

in this code:

```
acme_sinamelk_userArea:
pattern: /user
defaults: { _controller: AcmeSinamelkBundle:User:userAreaHome }

acme_sinamelk_userLogin:
    pattern: /userlogin
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeSinamelkBundle:Default:index }

acme_sinamelk_test:
  pattern:    /usera
  defaults:  { _controller: AcmeSinamelkBundle:Default:index }
```

when a user wants to go /usera it directs to /userlogin url and this is the problem.

thank you in advance.

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I edit the question a little in order to make it obvious more.I want to when a visitor wanna go http://localhost/usera Symfony doesn't redirect her to login page!

Comment: in other words only /user and /user/... patterns need to check for login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not any idea of what happened but whenI changed /userlogin to /login all things are okay now.